# How change action BackButton in UISplitViewController?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have Split View Controller.
I want change action back buttun on swift.
What me do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "YourNewButton", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, target: self, action: "doSomething")
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button

}

func doSomething()
{
    //do something
    var vc = YourDestinationViewController()

    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Tried. Aktion performed, but does not go into other view controller.
There are other options?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean, doesnt go "Back" to previous controller?

Comment: Yes. I use this code to initially opened detailviewcontroller: "if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
            detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
            if let detailViewController = detailViewController {
                detailViewController.cityWeather = weatherData.cities[0]
            }"

Comment: Tried. Doesn't go "Back" to previous controller. Thanks!

Comment: I get error. Please see my project https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gr7q9igyrwhqh73/AACqBSX8LiyzHc1SkJDhETtAa?dl=0

Comment: Text error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier CityCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'